# Elasticsearch "boost" not working when inside "filter"

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to `boost` matches on a certain field over another.

This works fine:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "boost": 2,
            "mainField": "foo"
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "otherField": "foo"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When i see the documents matched on `mainField`, i see they have a `_score` of `2.0` as expected.

But when i wrap this same query in a `filter`:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "terms": {
                  "boost": 2,
                  "mainField": "foo"
                }
              },
              {
                "terms": {
                  "otherField": "foo"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The `_score` for all documents is `0.0`.

The same thing happens for `multi_match`. By itself (e.g inside a `query`) it works fine, but inside a `bool + filter`, it doesn't work.

Can someone explain why this is the case? I need to wrap in a filter due to the way my app composes queries.

Some context might also help: I'm trying to return documents that match on either `mainField` or `otherField`, but *sort* the ones matching on `mainField` first, so i figured `boost` would be the most appropriate choice here. But let me know if there is a better way.

Answer (score 1):

The `filter` queries are always executed in the filter context. It will always return a score of zero and only contribute to the filtering of documents.

Refer to this [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context), to know more about filter context

Due to this, you are not getting a `_score` of 2.0, even after applying boost, in the second query

Comment: thanks. makes sense. what are my options then? a) not use a filter, b) don't score, but sort some other way? (curious on b, if it can be done)